# Не записывать значение в сессию

Tags: php

Есть значение, точное название я его не знаю, оно автоматически передаётся в переменную сессии `PHPSESSID`, как вытащить это значение из `PHPSESSID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Выведет весь массив значений, содержащихся в сессии.
Рекомендую ознакомиться с [документацией](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы ведете речь об имени сессии. Получить его можно через функцию [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-name.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump(session_name()); // выводим имя текущей сессии
```